# Python code to copy a folder from one container to another container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am currently writing a Python code for copying a folder from one container to another container.
There is no Kubectl and Docker command in the container
Is there any way to scp from one container to another container

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Official Python client library for kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to do anything including file copy. Client libraries are used to interact with apiserver just like kubectl utility.

I think it is implemented in this [commit](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/commit/e0d4cdc68520581c8173d088106985136f4a3caf).